# Copying audio file, issue with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, fwrite, fread

I was wondering if someone could help me with a problem that I'm having. I'm fairly sure that it's a pointer issue (read: I'm VERY much a C beginner), but I've been struggling with it for a fair while and have been unable to fix the issue (despite reading reference pages).

My code is meant to copy a .WAV file using two functions (the function prototypes are fixed). First it reads the file, then it writes a new file using the data samples from the old file. The header is defined in "R_WAV.h" as a typedef struct. The code is run from this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "R_WAV.h"

//Function Declarations
int read_WAV(header_type *header, char **data, char *filename);
int write_WAV(header_type *header, char *data, char *filename);

int main()
{
    //Run read_WAV
    {
        header_type *header;
        char *filename[] = {//Various files};
        char **data;
        read_WAV(header, data, *filename);
    }
    //Run write_WAV
    {
        header_type *header;
        char *filename[] = {//Various files};   
        char *data;
        write_WAV(header, data, *filename);
    }

    //Run read_WAV again on new files to ensure header info is valid
    {
    header_type *header;
    char *filename[] = {//output files from write};
    char *data;
    read_WAV(header, data, *filename);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

The read_WAV function I've written (abbreviated slightly) is:

```
int read_WAV(header_type *header, char **data, char *filename)
{   

    unsigned char   buffer4[4];
    unsigned char   buffer2[2];

    FILE    *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");    //Open file

    //Code here that checks if file successfully opened

    //If file valid, find length of file
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);    //Place position at EoF
    int size = ftell(fp);       //Read the current value
    rewind(fp);                 //Reset position

    //Code here that checks if file size < min. header size, if true exits

    header = (void*)malloc(size);

    //Reading RIFF string
    fread(header->ChunkID, sizeof(header->ChunkID), 1, fp);
    printf("\nChunkID: %s \n", (header->ChunkID));
```

And so on, until it comes time to read the data:

```
//Read DATA samples
char *buffer_data = (char*)malloc(header->Subchunk2Size);    
fread(buffer_data,1,(header->Subchunk2Size),fp);

//Error checking code here for if buffer==NULL

*data = buffer_data;

fclose(fp);
return(1);
}
```

The write_WAV function is:

```
int write_WAV(header_type *header, char *data, char *filename)
{
    char n_file[50];                            //Init. for new filename    
    int data_size = header->Subchunk2Size;      //Hold size of data chunk

    //CODE TO ALTER FILENAME (working properly)

    //Open new file (COPY_of_filename)
    FILE * fp_w = fopen(n_file, "wb");

    //Check to see if file was successfully created
    if (fp_w==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nUnable to create file.");
        return(-1);
    }

    //Write header to new file (first 44 bytes)
    fwrite(header, 1, 44, fp_w);

    //Write data to new file
    fwrite(data, 1, data_size, fp_w);
fclose(fp_w);
return (1);

}
```

I'm running into two main issues:

1) I can only get the header info (first 44 bytes) to write properly in write_WAV() if I open one of the .WAV files in that function, then use fread and a buffer to store it. Does it have to be done this way? Is there another way to use the *header that will result in this data being accessible from read_WAV() without needing to reopen the old file in write_WAV()?

2) I can't get the data samples to copy over properly. Even when I read in the header as above (and check that the header info is all correct), all I get is corrupt noise upon opening the new file. I've been trying to research this, but I've gotten nowhere. Could someone help explain/point to the mistakes in what I've done, and what I need to do in order to resolve them?

I know this is really simple stuff, and I wish that my brain was working enough to figure it out by myself. Like I said, I've read reference pages, but I'm still not getting anywhere. Not really firing on all cylinders right now.

Thank you for any (much needed) assistance!

Comment: Best if you ask about one problem at a time. And please be precise in explaining what problems you are observing. "I can only get the header info (first 44 bytes) to write properly"..so what do you observe about the data? It didn't get written at all? Incomplete data was written? garbage data was written? What...?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. There are two operations that have to be performed. First, the header data (which is contained in the first 44 bytes) is written to the file (getting the data section isn't related to this). I can only get that information if I call the readf() again. I figured that out, though, I think - I've closed the file that contains the header info, so there's nothing there when I try to use fwrite().

Comment: There is **no** need to cast the return of `malloc`, e.g. `(void*)malloc(size);` The return of `malloc` is `void *` so the cast is duplicative. Further, since `void *` can be cast to/from any other pointer type, there is never a need to cast the return of `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the block scoping of `data` in `main` in a few places.

That is, when you read in the file, because of variable scoping, you lose the pointer to the data. That is, when you do the write, the pointer it uses points to random memory.

I think you also have the same problem for the `header` pointer [although I didn't address that issue below, the fix would be similar]. Also, note that in the two read blocks, the type used for `header` is inconsistent even though they do the same thing.

Here's a version annotated with the bugs:

```
int main()
{
    //Run read_WAV
    {
        header_type *header;
        char *filename[] = {//Various files};
// NOTE/BUG: this is scoped to _this_ block, so the write section below won't
// see it
// NOTE/BUG: this should be char *data and the function call should use &data
        char **data;
        read_pcm_wavefile(header, data, *filename);
    }
    //Run write_WAV
    {
        pcm_wavefile_header_type *header;
        char *filename[] = {//Various files};
// NOTE/BUG: this scoped 'data' declaration has none of the data in the read
// sectioon above
        char *data;
        write_pcm_wavefile(header, data, *filename);
    }

    //Run read_WAV again on new files to ensure header info is valid
    {
    pcm_wavefile_header_type *header;
    char *filename[] = {//output files from write};
    char *data;
    read_pcm_wavefile(header, data, *filename);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Here's a fixed version:

```
int main()
{
    char *data;

    //Run read_WAV
    {
        header_type *header;
        char *filename[] = {//Various files};
        read_pcm_wavefile(header, &data, *filename);
    }

    //Run write_WAV
    {
        pcm_wavefile_header_type *header;
        char *filename[] = {//Various files};
        write_pcm_wavefile(header, data, filename[0]);
    }

    free(data);

    //Run read_WAV again on new files to ensure header info is valid
    {
        pcm_wavefile_header_type *header;
        char *filename[] = {//output files from write};
        read_pcm_wavefile(header, &data, filename[0]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I've fixed that up. Still unable to get a proper output, which I'm thinking is in the passing of the data/pointer from each function?

As I mentioned you need to do the same for `header` because `main` needs the pointer to be filled in by your read function. As it is, after the read call, the value of `header` in `main` is *unchanged* (i.e. *not* updated by `read_WAV` as you'd like).

Change:

```
int read_WAV(header_type *header, char **data, char *filename)
```

Into:

```
int read_WAV(header_type **header, char **data, char *filename)
```

And, make all corresponding adjustments in `main` and `read_WAV`

Also, apply the same scoping fix in `main` for `header` that was done for `data` (i.e. `header` should *not* be block scoped, but, rather *function* scoped).

Because, even with the prototype change to `read_WAV`, `main` would lose the `header` value that `read_WAV` tried to pass back and `write_WAV` would get a garbage `header` pointer.

After you get this working, think about the *temporal* duration of the block scoped variables vs function scoped variables. In other words, if you set a variable, when does the value "go out of scope" [and become invalid].

For comparison, here's a version that does *not* use block scoped variables:

```
int
main(void)
{
    char *data;
    header_type *header;
    char *infiles[FILECOUNT] = {//Various files};
    char *outfiles[FILECOUNT] = {//Various files};

    for (int fidx = 0;  fidx < FILECOUNT;  ++fidx) {
        //Run read_WAV
        read_pcm_wavefile(&header, &data, infiles[fidx]);

        //Run write_WAV
        write_pcm_wavefile(header, data, outfiles[fidx]);

        free(header);
        free(data);

        //Run read_WAV again on new files to ensure header info is valid
        read_pcm_wavefile(&header, &data, outfiles[fidx]);

        free(header);
        free(data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Craig. I've fixed that up. Still unable to get a proper output, which I'm thinking is in the passing of the data/pointer from each function?

Comment: The big HINT is in `int read_WAV(header_type *header, char **data, char *filename);`, specifically the `char **data,` tells you you are passing the **address of** a `pointer to char`, telling you that you will most likely allocate for `data` in `read_WAV`. The same applies to `header` (which you discovered). You can either allocate before you call the function and pass `char *` or pass `char **` and allocate within.

Comment: RE: Update. Whoops, sorry, I was reading on mobile and for some reason missed the very first bit. I didn't catch labelling the two different headers differently in my question - they are the same as each other in my program, though. As for the pointer adjustment to header, it's fixed as: int funct_name(header_type *header...). But you were perfectly correct - I applied the scoping fix to header and removed the header malloc(), and it's now reading/writing the header perfectly! Still haven't gotten the data copying over yet, but I'm sure that I'll get there.

Comment: And thank you very, very much, Craig, for your words about block vs function scoped. Putting it like that was really, really helpful for understanding the concept, and it'll make a big difference for me in the future!

Comment: . . . Hallelujah - just got the data fixed. Reading your reply, Craig, and your comment, David - something just clicked, and my mistake semi-jumped out at me after a quick scan through. The program is now running correctly. Thank you very much!